# Map of MapFragment gets loaded with lag when returning from another activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

As far as I can see, `MapFragment` has an issue with transition animations. All views on the layout are getting shown immediately, including the MapFragment's own views (like zoom buttons). But the map itself gets loaded with a lag only after the animation is completed.

In order to illustrate the problem, I did the following:

1. I changed one of the Activities in the **Google maps android API examples** slightly. It opens a blank activity via an Action Item. When I click back button, the map gets loaded, but only after the transition is completed.
2. I exaggerated the transition effect a little bit, so that you can see the problem better. I set the **transition animation speed** in **Developer Options** to **5x**. Even on 1x speed, this lag is disturbing though.

See this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12SEotktlXI

Do you have any suggestion to prevent this lag? Why do all views get loaded immediately but the map itself doesn't?

Testing environment: Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2, unrooted

**Edit:** This problem also occures when MapView is used instead of MapFragment.

Comment: Have tried to test it on other devices? I noticed it only on Nexus 5.. Galaxy S3 showed different behavior...

Comment: Yes, definitely. I tried it on HTC Desire SV, and there was no lag. I think that's because they don't use transition animations. When I turn transition animations off on my Nexus 5 (settings > developer options > transition animations), the lag disappears too.

Comment: So it's something related to KitKat... maybe a bug.

Comment: I think it's a maps API bug because all other views get loaded immediately but only the map doesn't...

Answer (score -3):

Reason: Its because as soon as you settings activity will be shown, the map activity will be on its onpause() state; thus, I assume android management reclaimed the memory from the map activity.

Solution:
Make a static class and declare you map statically there, to avoid android from reclaiming the memory used by your map.

Ex.

```
//your static class
public class MapData{
  public static GoogleMap map;
}

//your map activity
public class MapActivity extends Activity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(MapData.map != null)
       MapData.map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  }
}
```

Comment: At least make sure that onDestroy the static var is cleaned up.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work. I replaced every occurence of `mMap` in RetainMapDemoActivity example with `MapData.map` but the map still has lag when I come back from the dummy activity... :(